# How can j extract from a jsonb column some of the informations and merge to a summary with a new group name?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have the folowing table points:

| node_id | tags | geom |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"name": "NoName", "brand": "NoName", "amenity": "fuel", "wheelchair": "yes", "opening_hours": "Mo-Su,PH 07:00-24:00"} | POINT(x,y) |

I have a Column "tags"

```json
{
  "name": "NoName",
  "brand": "NoName",
  "amenity": "fuel",
  "wheelchair": "yes",
  "opening_hours": "Mo-Su,PH 07:00-24:00"
}
```

now i want only the following informations in a new column tags in a new table points_red with a postgresql query:

```json
{
  "addInfo": {
    "name": "NoName",
    "brand": "NoName",
    "amenity": "fuel"
  }
}
```

in a new table points_red

| node_id | tags | geom |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {{"addInfo" : {"name": "NoName", "brand": "NoName", "amenity": "fuel"}} | POINT(x,y) |

Answer (score 2):

**Update post for insert statement**:

Sample: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=902e4c01f661c53df8a4db0fbd58b8a5)

```sql
insert into points_red (node_id, tags, geom)
select
  node_id,
  jsonb_build_object(
    'addInfo',
    jsonb_build_object(
      'name',
      tags ->> 'name',
      'brand',
      tags ->> 'brand',
      'amenity',
      tags ->> 'amenity'
    )
  ),
  geom
from
  points
where tags notnull;
```

---

Query structure and sample data: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d7fadfb29d678cac8f56a753410f1e77)

You can use one of the below queries:

1. With `tags` path:

```sql
select
  jsonb_build_object(
    'addInfo',
    jsonb_build_object(
      'name',
      tags ->> 'name',
      'brand',
      tags ->> 'brand',
      'amenity',
      tags ->> 'amenity'
    )
  )
from
  test
where tags notnull;
```

2. With extract jsonb column to record:

```sql
select
  jsonb_build_object(
    'addInfo',
    jsonb_build_object(
      'name',
      e.name,
      'brand',
      e.brand,
      'amenity',
      e.amenity
    )
  )
from
  test t
  cross join jsonb_to_record(tags) as e(name text, brand text, amenity text)
where t.tags notnull;
```

Comment: thx, how does it works if the tags are in a table names points and the table has the columns node_id, tags, geom for example

Comment: edited the question, sorry for that

Comment: Do you want to insert a new JSON structure into a new table?

Comment: yes it would be fine

Comment: Post has been updated for insert statement